# Bootstrap collapse menuitems (li) missing the regular listitem styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am usually pretty used to find out my own issues when it comes to Bootstrap styling and elements, but this one.. just keeps giving me a headache, and therefore i  need to ask you guys here.

I'm overriding some bootstrap styles, like the dropdown (hamburgermenu trigger dropdown) so it goes on top of other elements, rather than moving it downwards..

If you inspect my JSFiddle example after expanding the menu you see that i'm missing the relation to :

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a
```

.. the styling is completely gone, and i dont know why.

Here is a link to my  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yj71e0hf/4/)

Comment: May be you are using your own css and bootstrap css at a time.

Comment: There is not list styling applied. you just need to apply your own or undo your changes

Comment: Can you change your JSFiddle to just have reproduceable code.. right now there is just too much unwanted CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.

its here in this HTML

```
 <a id="lnkTeamOverviewMobile" style="color:black" class="visible-sm" href="/EventCalendar" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$lnkTeamOverviewMobile&#39;,&#39;&#39;)">Eventkalender</a>
```

you have a class `visible-sm` which is set to `display:none!important` in bootstrap.css , If you use this class you are saying that to display this element only when you are in a small device, And Computer Monitors are usually Medium..

**Remove the class `visible-sm` and it must work fine**

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yj71e0hf/7/)**

Comment: Thanks :) Such an obvious, but yet... invisible answer :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)